# Book reviewing current state of research on complex networks

Tags: resource-recommendations, complex-systems, graph-theory, network

Can anybody recommend a book reviewing the current state of knowledge and active research on [complex networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_networks)?

Not primarily a textbook but a true review of the field - ideally with references to applications where relevant.

Comment: Seems to be a topic for either  [theoretical computer science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) or [mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) (possibly even [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/)) In any case check the FAQs first.

Comment: Sorry, but network theory is also a branch of physics. It's statistical physics, or complex system theory, two branches for which Physics StackExchange has tags. I'm working in a research group made entirely of physicists that works only on them. There is a section of arXiv called "Disordered Systems and Neural Networks" and it's part of cond-mat.
Is this enough?

Comment: @Bzazz The fact that my question was closed as "off topic" led me to conclude that there are no research physicists in this forum. Since you do work in the field, do you know of any good texts? What literature do the members of your group recommend to new PhD candidates to help orient themselves in the field and its recent developments? If you have an answer which does not fit into a comment, let me know and we will find a way.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really just started to work with networks (for my master thesis). I've been suggested reading S. Dorogovtsev's Lectures on Complex Networks and Newman's review (http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S003614450342480). Newman has also written a huge book, covering networks in an interdisciplinar way. I have some more articles to read, by professors of the group I'll work with, but perhaps they are too specific.